# How do I send logs from a VPC without an internet gateway/VPC endpoint to CloudWatch Logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a only one VPC which has an internet gateway. We'll call it the main VPC.
The other VPCs are connected to the main VPC through a VPC peering connection. There is no public access to those VPCs.

I'm not in a region where it is possible to create a VPC Endpoint for CloudWatch.

What should I do?

Comment: I wonder if you can create a route table entry in the "other vpc" from 0.0.0.0/0 to the main VPC, and from there traffic out to the internet gateway from there. You will incur [data transfer fees](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/vpc-peering-basics.html#vpc-peering-pricing). You might be better off putting an internet gateway in your "other VPC" and using security groups / NACLs to limit them rather than routing things around.

Comment: I'm not sure how to define such setup.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure how to limit the access to CloudWatch logs if I do create an internet gateway on the other VPC.

Comment: You might be best off hiring an AWS consultant to help.